# Stopping a while loop php

Tags: php, comet, long-integer, long-polling

Interested in the question - how to properly stop a while loop with sleep inside.
The fact that I implemented "**long poll**" to quickly update information on the website (warning, other information).

**THE ESSENCE OF THE SCRIPT**

**1.** We will send GET-request to PHP-page in which the script is located.

**2.** The script runs the loop **while**.

**3.** In this series there **2** conditions and sleep(1) at the end, which suspends the execution of the loop.

**-** if the loop runs more seconds **30** - stop the execution of the loop, respectively, and the script.

**-** If your site has new information, say "alert" - derive results to the user and stop the cycle.

**PROBLEM**
If the user closes the browser window, or reloads the page - a new query is executed on the script, which will start the cycle again. But in this case, the previous execution of the loop **while** will not stop until they work at least one condition within it. If a user sends a lot of requests to the page - the server's memory begins to boot, and as a result all hanging until all **while** will not stop the execution.

**QUESTION**
How to stop the cycle and the script as a whole, when you run the page is reloaded or a client?
While at the moment I did the following.
When you run the script we generate receive a random number that is assigned to the variable, and the same with the session. Further inland while doing a condition in which the variable must be the value of the session. If false - stop the cycle.
If we run the script on the new - the value of the session changes and accordingly all prior performance while stopped.
Can I use that option? And how much is safe?

**UPDATE.PHP**

```
 // Initialize the user's session
 $session = Session::instance();

        $rand = rand();
        $session->set('user_update_key', $rand);
        $key = $rand;

        $limit = 20;
        $seconds = 0;

        set_time_limit($limit + 1);

        while (TRUE) {
            if (Session::instance()->get('user_update_key') == $key) {

                if (there are updates. if there is - output) {
                    echo 'update information';
                    flush();
                    exit;
                }
                if ($seconds == $limit) { // complete the loop at the expiration of the time.
                    echo 'Close';
                    flush();
                    exit;
                }
                $seconds++;
            } else {
                unset($session, $rand, $key, $notice, $mysession, $last_notice, $limit, $notise_return, $seconds);
                flush();
                exit;
            }
            session_write_close();
            sleep(1);
            session_start();
```

}

Comment: `while (TRUE)` <- Am sure you don't need this, do you?

Comment: You can use continue; keyword for terminating loop inside loop.

Comment: Do you really need to session_write_close(); / session_start(); ? How is the update process being initiated, is it possible to simply set a timeout of 30 seconds there?

Comment: How about doing the loop in javascript using `setInterval`, and simplifying the script to just the `Session::instance()->get('user_update_key') == $key` without a loop ?

Comment: If the user manually starts doing a lot of requests for a script - it will start a lot of "while" simultaneously, which is load the server

Comment: Well, don't do the loop in PHP then, do it in javascript and do not allow the user to simply repoll, leave that to the Javascript loop.

Answer (score 2):

Be warned that in general PHP and Apache are not meant for long-polling. I don't know how things are when you use nginx, but few months ago I had to do some long-polling job on Apache. Everything looked good until we went production. It turns out that limitations of Apache prevent you from maintaining long-lasting connections.

Server hanged and refused to accept any new requests after allowing about 20 users to log in and open 3-4 cards of webpage. There are also browsers limitations preventing you from maintaining too many http connections to one host. There's workaround though - using subdomains.

I tried to figure out how to solve id, asked a dozen questions here on StackOverflow and everything ended in using node.js + socket.io which is lightweight and handles thousands of simultaneous connections with ease.

**I know that this post isn't answer to your original question, but after I lost few weeks on developing something that won't work I hope that you might find these informations helpful.**

Answer (score 0):

Your while condition is unchangable, while in practice it is not.
The function sleep() will return 0 if succesful, hence if you rewrite your while condition reaction on the change of the return value of sleep(), then might it work as designed, see:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

With threads and other functions is it always important to know on which OS you are working. I have Ubuntu and it reacts different then the documentation stated.

```
function interruptedSleep(){
  $cond = true;
  while($cond){
   $i = sleep(10);
   if($i == 0){
     $cond = false;
   }
  }
 }
```

When you interrupt the sleep by closing the browser will the sleep function return 0 and the while loop being aborted and the program will continu directly after the while. It will not throw an exception.

Comment: Set as you said. All time displays false.
:( 
In this case, the page is open.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a cronjob to run the processes in the background on a regular basis, and then place AJAX on the web pages that pull the database checking for your alerts.  Otherwise you're going to run into performance issues.

Comment: You mean, that would be created for each user cronjob, which runs in the background. A ajax requests have been made ​​long for him?

Comment: Meaning that you have one cronjob that runs in the background that's only job is to send emails.  You can still have it be a PHP script, that grabs all the records from the database that need to be sent, and it then sends them.  On the web site / application side the ajax just runs every X seconds to check if there are any alerts from the database it needs to show, if there is an alert it pops up or does what you want it to do.

Comment: You can be notified instantly using this technology?

Comment: Yup!  AJAX can run continuously on your page and update your screen when certain conditions are applicable in the database, or whatever the input is.

Comment: But Cronjob understand that to give, and what is not? That is how the identity of the users?

Comment: Not sure what you're saying here.  But basically a cronjob is a timer that you can setup on the server to run ever X minutes, or X hours, or X days or whatever you want.  The script you would setup would just grab all the records in your database that have been "queued" to send.  It then grabs the user information and message details for each record and sends them individually.  The cronjob would reference the PHP script you write that would do the query, send the mail, and change the status of the record in the database to sent.

Comment: I understand, Cronjob - it is a way of the script at the appointed time.
In my case, notification must be displayed instantly.
With regard to their presence in the database - no problem.
I need to use the technology for long poll "detained" the user's connection to the server.
According to your logic - Cronjob automatically searches and send posts.
But notice on the site I do not go to the mailbox. They pop up directly in the user's browser.
Doing each inquiry Ajax 10-20 seconds - do not, as is the load on the server.

Comment: We need to do ajax request and wait for the server will render the result.
While the client is waiting for - the server also checks and puts a pause sleep.
Maybe I misunderstood you. With English problem. I'm from Ukraine :)
If it is possible - please send picture of the algorithm - I will be very grateful!

Comment: You can do AJAX on click, or on a timer based, or event based condition to actually push to the users browser.  The cronjob is just for processing the mail behind the scenes.  The notifications appear instantly via your method on the application side.

Comment: You don't need to use any sleep methods is what I'm saying.  The AJAX just runs as you need or on event based, and then you can popup the notification inside javascript to push the alert to a DIV tag or other tag on your site to popup the alert instantly.